# Forcing image to get the max-width keeping the aspect ratio within a max-height

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

How can I force the image to get the higher possible width without trespassing the `max-height` argument, and keeping the aspect ratio?

```css
img {
      display:block;
      max-height: 100px;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: auto;
}
```

```html
<table border=1 style="table-layout: fixed; width: 500px;">
<thead>
  <th style="width: 100px;">
    100px
  </th>
  <th style="width: 400px;">
    400px
  </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      A image
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x100">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      This image could be larger
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x50">
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it in a container that forces those constraints should work for you:

```css
img {
      display:block;
      width: 100%;
}

.cell-wrapper {
      display:block;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 100px;
      overflow-y: hidden;
      width: auto;
}
```

```html
<table border=1 style="table-layout: fixed; width: 1000px;">
<thead>
  <th style="width: 100px;">
    100px
  </th>
  <th style="width: 400px;">
    400px
  </th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      A image
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x100">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      This image could be larger
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="cell-wrapper">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x50">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```